# How to use find on dirs with white spaces?

Tags: linux, bash

Here is something strange.

```
mkdir -p "1/2 3/4"
touch 1/2\ 3/4/file.jpg
for f in $(find . -type f -name \*jpg); do echo "${f}"; done
```

This returns

```
./1/2
3/4/file.jpg
```

and not

```
./1/2 3/4/file.jpg
```

How do I get `find` for preserve white spaces so the file path is correct?

Comment: See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind

Comment: Also [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in several ways, but I find it much better to do it this way:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg | while read i ; do echo "Procesing $i..." ; done
```

Comment: This will fail in the (quite unlikely) case where one of the filenames contains a newline.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `-print0` option along with `xargs -0`. For instance:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

This would work no matter the content of the file names (even newlines would be handled correctly).

Comment: I was going to suggest this too, however this groups as many filenames together as it can (as will fit on a command line) and executes the command for each batch, not for each file. That's probably a better thing to do instead of a for loop anyway, or `find . -type f -name \*.jpg -exec something {} \+` (note the `\+` instead of `\;`)

Comment: @Stephen: You can use `xargs -n 1` to have xargs run on one file at a time.

Answer (score 2):

See the difference between:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg -exec echo {} \;
```

and:

```
find . -type f -name \*.jpg -exec echo \"{}\" \;
```